# I need to convert trackbar value to hex bytes and display it on text box

Tags: hex, trackbar

In c# i have a trackbar with range of 0-254.
I want to convert each digit to hex byte, meaning that 250 will be "32-35-30"
and display that in a text box
how can i do that?

I dont have any code for example

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple task:

```
string s = "250";
byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
string s2=BitConverter.ToString(array);
```

Now `s2` has the desired output.